# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 18: did not find expectedkey

Tags: yaml

pasting my yaml file here

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  labels:
    {{- include "ingress-nginx.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  {{- range .Values.ipRanges | quote }}
  - {{ . }}
  {{- end }}
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    {{- include "ingress-nginx.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Please help me identify the issue. I tried several things but it didn't work. I did yamllint but those issues that yamllint shows were previously there and still it worked fine. i just added this three lines   and it is giving error

{{- range .Values.ipRanges | quote }}

- {{ . }}
  {{- end }}

Comment: and this works for other yaml except this one

Comment: Try indenting those three lines

Comment: That is not a YAML document. Each of the lines starting with `{{` should be taken out, they are garbage for the YAML processor. I think you are mistaken and this is not a YAML document at all, but some template that could generate a YAML document, in that case this question is incorrectly tagged `yaml`.